# How to send file as attachment to the Microsoft Teams channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have check the Graph API using which we can send message to the channel but I am not getting any example to send files to the channel as an attachment can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Check this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Hi Abhijit ,Is this document helpful to send the file over Microsoft team's channel?

Comment: My understanding is  Graph currently allows to send file only with One drive `connects with files across OneDrive`  and sharepoint document libraries

Answer (score 1):

You can post messages with card attachments referencing existing SharePoint files using the Microsoft Graph APIs for [OneDrive and SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/). Using the Graph APIs requires obtaining access to a user's OneDrive folder (for *personal* and *groupchat* files) or the files in a team's channels (for channel files) through the standard OAuth 2.0 authorization flow.

Please have a look at [Send and receive files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files#using-the-microsoft-graph-apis) documentation.